# Class.forName(com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver) not working in Liberty8.5

Tags: java, jdbc, classnotfoundexception, websphere-liberty, dbconnection

I'm trying to configure an application which is currently running in websphere 8.0 to websphere liberty. This application is having creating jdbc connection using:

```
Driver DB2Driver = (java.sql.Driver) Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
```

This is working perfectly in websphere full profile. But not in liberty. I tried creating a library to point to "C:/sqllib/java" directory which contains the db2java.zip. But its still not working. The errors I'm getting is:

```
[err] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
[err]     at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClassCommonLibraryClassLoaders(AppClassLoader.java:403)
[err]     at [internal classes]
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You haven't needed this line of code since 2005, unless IBM were slow implementing JDBC 4. They certainly must have by now. Just remove it. They may have changed the driver class name, but since JDBC 4 it auto-registers itself and gets found when you use a DB2 JDBC URL, so it doesn't matter what they may have changed it to.

Comment: Why would you do that? Isn't the datasource configured and the JDBC driver already loaded and tested? Just get a connection from the datasource; don't create connections manually.

Answer (score 2):

You are pointing to wrong archive, that one is with old driver. You need to define it like this in server.xml:

```
<library id="DB2JCC4Lib">
    <fileset dir="C:/sqllib/java" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"/>
</library>
```

I'd also suggest using dataSource instead of Driver:

```
<dataSource id="db2" jndiName="jdbc/db2">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2JCC4Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="SAMPLEDB" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000"/>
</dataSource>
```

If you need driver see [bkail post explaining how to add classloader](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/23946/classfornamecomibmdb2jccdb2driver-not-working-in-liberty85//23947). In short:

> [..] You would need to add a
>
> ```
> <classloader commonLibraryRef="DB2JCC4Lib" />
> ```
>
> to your `<application>` in server.xml.